# PWA are restricted in certain countries? Like China?

Tags: web, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching, restriction, great-firewall-of-china

Are PWA are restricted in certain countries?

PWA is setup using workbox, default given in 'create-react-app'.

```
My managerial team says they are blocked in China.
```

Currently our site is using only Google Analytics apart from normal data API .

Checked my PWA site via https://www.vpnmentor.com/tools/test-the-great-china-firewall/
and its clear and can be accessed.

How can i test my PWA for the same from my own country or the client's country(USA).

Comment: A PWA is just a website with additional functionality. Some websites are blocked. Some libraries you MAY use with a PWA may be blocked. Some libraries you use MAY not function with the approved browsers in China. I see nothing that says ALL websites that have PWA functionality are ALL blocked.

Answer (score 1):

#### Override Geolocation With Chrome DevTools

You can now override you geolocation in devtools. For more info how to do that check [that google article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/geolocation)

#### Custom user browser configuration

You should remember that user may have custom browser configuration. Or they may have some additional restrictions if they trying to access you site from office internet for example.

#### USA/China relationship

Regarding to last events it may happen that there will be no android phones in China soon. Huawei developing own os and they may not implement PWA at all.